# Loading image from database with inconsistent results across servers

Tags: php, postgresql, image-processing

I am loading images from a single PostgreSQL database shared currently by my production and development instances.  This is already a little inaccurate - the production server isn't live yet, which is why it's okay they share a DB.  The software itself is written in PHP5.3.

The issue is this: my image storage routine works on both servers.  An image stored using either branch can be displayed properly in the production branch.  However, the images are completely nonviewable on the production side.

Invoking the image display script directly yields the discovery that the data returned by each is markedly different.  The production server provides (excerpt):

`‰PNG  IHDR99zÒ IDAThL&³Ùaaaýýýþþþþþþþþþýýýýýý" ø÷øëðïêññçîîàëêßêêìööPPP;'(8&'"þþúúüýýýþþÿþõÛëìÇÙÙÈÞÝòúúLLL P45B-,üý÷÷ýýÿÿÿÿþþþÿýýþþÿÿþþÿ íÿºÒÒµÕÔòúúKKKÿÿÿF**]=?ýýõõÿÿÿ`

while the development server delivers (excerpt):

`x89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d4948445200000039000000390802000000037a14d200002000494441546805014c26b3d9016161610000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

for the same image.  Curiously, the development server's response echoes what the actual database appears to be storing.

The relevant code appears to be identical between instances.  Investigating php.ini yields only minor differences relating to error reporting.  I'm all but certain this is a server communication issue but I am at a loss as to what exactly is causing it.

Comment: You'll see this repeated across the site: storing images in a database is almost never a good idea. Any reason you can't store them as regular files?

Comment: Looks like an encoding problem...

Comment: because it would be a logistical nightmare when things such as the number of files and how closely tied images are to content.  moving the images outside the database would introduce synchronization difficulties.

Comment: plus, the fact that it's failing on me for reasons undetermined is unpleasant and if i don't fix it now i may have more problems down the line.

Comment: @Frankie: yeah, that's what i thought too.  I'm not sure what could cause that in this context, which is why I asked here.

Comment: @Kerin, I would also agree on keeping the images out of the database. Even though it's a tangent to what you've asked and you should defenittly find WHY things are happening the way they are try to implement a system that stores files on disk. Just have an ID for the image on the database and store them on disk. You'll thank yourself latter. Think in terms of content delivery (static vs non-static), difficulties in horizontal scaling of databases, etc...

Comment: @Frankie, I appreciate your separation of the issue at hand and this second topic.  My predicament is thus: I have to deliver a lot of images of relatively low (most around 2kb, some as much as 500kb) data which is highly individualized to the user, but which doesn't change terribly often.  The images are however user-supplied and of a very complicated hierarchy.

Comment: As a result, organizing the images by directory instead of in a more abstract fashion inside the database represents a significant engineering challenge.  Static content images are not stored in the database, only user data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a configuration mismatch :

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-BYTEA-OUTPUT

Comment: This bumped me in the right direction.  Setting `SET bytea_output = "escape";` prior to my retrieval query fixed the issue, and now I am changing the setting permanently to avoid query overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the returned data are the same, but in one case the string is displayed as raw output, in the other case is given in output as an hex string.

As you can [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Examples) `89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A` is the magic number for png files and if you convert it in ascii you'll obtain `\211 P N G \r \n \032 \n` which are the content of the first 8 byte of the first output.

So you have to find why in one case the output is hex and in the other is raw, maybe a postgres settings or it could depend on how you're retrieving and displaying the content using php.

You should try to output the content of the image field using the command line or a tool which is not related to php. If in this way the output is the same you can restrict the search to your php.ini settings (in this case you should post some code on image retrieval).

Conversely if the output differs at postgres level you should investigate on your postgres settings on both servers.

Comment: could also be different versions of the libpq library or php/pgsql integration being compared?